# Whats the difference between the output of mencoder and libx264?

Tags: video-processing, libx264

i want to know the difference between video output of these two encoders (mencoder and libx264).
i guess they're not, since the video information of the codec have different names.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x264 will encode video using the h.264 codec and only supports a handful for containers. It will not encode audio, and will not encode video using other codecs such as vp8 (webm) theora, etc

mencoder will encode both audio and video and supports many more codecs and containers. Internally mencoder will x264 to encode h.264 video.